# Ruby STDIN.getch and printf

Tags: ruby, input, io

I was trying to make a basic spelling console app that using MacOS text to speech to say a word and the user is suppose to spell the word.

I only want to output alphabetic characters, so I used `STDIN.getch` instead if `gets` but I found when I spell the word quickly the outputted character get jumbled and duplicated, even though the outputted word is what I expect.

What am I doing wrong that it does not just output the letter that is being said and included in the final word?

Output when I spell horse quickly:

```
hoorsrese
horse
```

Code:

```
class Speaker
  def say(text)
    `say #{text}`
  end
end

require 'io/console'
class SpellMaster
  def initialize(speaker = Speaker.new)
    @speaker = speaker
  end

  def spell(word = 'word')
    @speaker.say "Spell #{word}"
    spelling = get_spelling
    if spelling == word
      @speaker.say('correct')
    else
      @speaker.say('incorrect')
    end
    gets
  end

  def get_spelling
    char = ''
    word = ''
    while char != "\r"
      char = get_letter
      word += char
    end
    printf("\n" + word)
    word.chomp
  end

  def get_letter
    char = STDIN.getch
    return '' unless /[a-z]/.match?(char) || char == "\r"
    print char
    @speaker.say(char)
    char
  end
end

SpellMaster.new.spell
```

edit: to remove class variable

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with `@@speaker` as that seems like a really clumsy way of doing a singleton, and if that's the case then that should be the concern of `Speaker`, not `SpellMaster`. However, if these are cheap to create, why can't each `SpellMaster` have its own instance?

Comment: Note that when you use backticks to execute shell commands you *must escape the arguments* or you can inadvertently run additional commands. Use [`shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) or `system("say", text)` which ensures the text is processed as an argument, not arbitrary shell commands.

Comment: @tadman just trying to make it something I could change in test. But after reading about class variable and instance variable, I will switch it to an instance variable.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the type about escaping, calling shell commands from ruby is new to me.

Comment: Yeah, `gets` is the way to go for line-based input. `getch` is hardly ever used because it's not very useful. For character-level control you'll want to use something like a Curses wrapper so you can pick up on other keys as well, like pressing shift or control, or separating press from release events.